# Why is this custom nemo action not turning up in the context menu?

Tags: cinnamon

Here are the contents of my `/home/usrname/.local/share/nemo/actions`

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=Add to portamusic
Comment=Transcodes each file Ogg Vorbis and copies it to portamusic
Exec=/home/usrname/bin/add-to-portamusic.sh %F
Selection=NotNone
Extensions=Any
EscapeSpaces=true
Terminal=true
Active=true
```

I wanted this option to turn up in the context menu when I right-click on a single folder or file or multiple. No such luck; the option is not in the context menu ever so far as I can see.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

All seems to be good.
May be check sh file permissions (to be execute).
Otherwise, the error is in the sh file.